Is there a way to read file change events from sharepoint for multiple sites?
I need to get file change events from SharePoint whenever any change happens for a document library across multiple sites.
I have been exploring a lot on reading file changes events from SharePoint. SharePoint trigger of logic app and power automate are site level. What we need is for it to be at a higher level to read changes for multiple sites.
I later explored SharePoint webhooks, but it also seems to get file change events at site level.
how can we read file changes events for multiple sites with a single webhook?

Easily, have multiple flows that catch the trigger by site and then feed that trigger data into one that has all of the shared logic for processing the changes. You can’t get away from needing multiple flows if you want to make use of the standard triggers.

there are 34000 sites, which is not possible

It may have been helpful to mention that in your question. Your requirement is next level, if even 10% of those sites are being hit regularly with changes then it’s going to be a busy day for LogicApps, potentially quite costly as well? If on consumption. To even poll that many sites regularly is a massive undertaking. Just over 4 a second constantly to get all done in a day.

Why can’t you use classic webhooks and then just do the work to set up all 340,000 sites? If that’s the requirement then that’s your solution. It’s still a single webhook but it’s not magic, the sites all have to know to send changes to that webhook endpoint.

@Pawan Poojary If you want to use Power Automate then you will have to create separate flows for each library. other approach will be to develop a logic app or a console application that runs on a VM, that run each X minutes/hours and check if the file was recently changed and read it accordingly. Using the console app or logic app you can loop through all sites and libraries within
the same app, no need to have separate apps.

Looping ain't possible. Need a single approach which checks at a higher level for multiple sites.

@PawanPoojary ok you can programmatically get all sites and loop through them and get the files recently modified OR did you try to call the search api to get the files from all sites at once ?
